# Get string from HTML

Tags: javascript

I need to get a date (just as a string) from the HTML below:

```
<div class="patNameAddress">
<strong>Lastname, Firstname</strong><br />
Stree Address<br />
City ST Zip<br />
<br />
EXP DATE:10-08-2011<br />
<div>
```

The date string is always in the mm-dd-yyyy format, and always preceded by EXP DATE:

How do I find this string on the page and return it to use as a variable?

Answer (score 9):

```
var matches = text.match(/EXP DATE:(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/));
```

`matches[1]` contains just the date, and `matches[0]` contains the entire match (i.e., it includes EXP DATE:).

Answer (score 1):

place the date in a span as such `<span class='date'>10-08-2011</span>` then using jQuery you can retrieve it by using

```
$(function(){
    alert($(".patNameAddress .date").text());
});
```

Comment: Yes, straight javascript...  And, I have no control over this page so cannot add the span class to the date...

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
function findDates(){
    var dates = [];
    $('.patNameAddress').each(function(){
        date_temp = $(this).html().match(/EXP DATE\:(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/);
        if (date_temp.length) dates.push(date_temp[1])
    });
    return dates;
}
```

Bonus: [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwick/MXqvv/)

Answer (score 1):

This gets the job done:

```
[].map.call( div.childNodes, function ( node ) {
    return node.nodeType === 3 ? node.data : '';
}).join( '' ).match(/EXP DATE:(.+)/)[1].trim()
```

where `div` is a reference to that DIV element.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2ahmy/1/

Note: this code will break if you run it on a DIV that doesn't have a "EXP DATE:" text in it.

Comment: Perfect.  Absolutely perfect.

Thank you so very much!

Comment: Oh.  One problem.  This doesn't work in IE9 for some reason...

Thoughts?

Comment: @kernmann I've run my demo in IE9 and it works. Do you get any errors? Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work?

Comment: I get no result.  Nothing happens.

This is the entire thing: http://jsfiddle.net/mens_et_nihil/FGNMm/

It does work if I take out the code you provided and substitute at date ("10-12-2011") for str in var s = (str)

Comment: @kernmann I have the same result in both Firefox and IE9 - the "expired" alert is displayed.

Comment: yes, on jsfiddle it works.  uploaded here it does not:

http://www.rpl.lib.nh.us/tools/EXPDATE.html

Comment: @kernmann Your DOCTYPE is triggering [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Replace it with `<!doctype html>` and it will work in IE.

Comment: And it DOES!  Thank you again for the code and the opportunity to learn something new!  ~kern

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, are `map` and `join` standard now? Would I be able to use them safely across browsers?

Comment: @VivinPaliath `join` is cross-browser, `map` doesn't work in IE8 (but you can [shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) it).